# How i am able to access EKS Cluster, though my User/Role ARN is not part of aws-auth CM?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-iam, amazon-eks, kubernetes-rbac

New to EKS, Learning.
I understand that Access can be provided to IAM Users/Roles by adding to the aws-auth config map, but when the cluster was created the first time, the AWS-auth has only one entry.

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  mapRoles: |
    - "groups":
      - "system:bootstrappers"
      - "system:nodes"
      "rolearn": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:role/test-eks"
      "username": "system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: aws-auth
  namespace: kube-system
```

kubeconfig file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: XXXXXXXXXXX
    server: https://XXXXXXXXXXXXX.XXX.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com
  name: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:cluster/test-eks
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:cluster/test-eks
    user: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:cluster/test-eks
  name: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:cluster/test-eks
current-context: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:cluster/test-eks
users:
- name: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:cluster/test-eks
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      args:
      - --region
      - us-east-1
      - eks
      - get-token
      - --cluster-name
      - test-eks
      command: aws
```

Question: How I am able to access Cluster as Admin? where it was defined in the cluster that I (IAM User) have cluster-admin access?
Please help me in understanding. Thank You in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html:

> When you create an Amazon EKS cluster, the IAM entity user or role...
> is automatically granted system:masters permissions in the cluster's
> RBAC configuration in the control plane.

You are already the admin as you are the creator of the cluster.

Comment: Thank You! I was so blind :). You saved my time Sir! Thanks Again.